# gRPC PHP Plugin Installation

Tags: php, grpc

I'm trying to follow gRPC tutorials from this [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/php#build-from-source). After several hours I'm stuck at the `grpc_php_plugin` installation. So started searching for a solution, I found a similar problem in GitHub issue. And the solution was this:

edit: I cloned gRPC v1.36.2

```
Just had the same issue. Using an older version works for me:

RUN cd /tmp && git clone -b v1.34.1 --depth 1 https://github.com/grpc/grpc && cd grpc && git submodule update --init && make grpc_php_plugin
```

I followed the steps and I installed `grpc_php_plugin`

But when I try to generate PHP libraries, I'm getting this error.

```
muratcolyaran@MSI:~/tutorial-grpc/app$ protoc --proto_path=protos --php_out=lib --grpc_out=lib protos/demo.proto --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/home/muratcolyaran/tmp/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin
protoc-gen-php: program not found or is not executable
--php_out: protoc-gen-php: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

The environment I use:

OS Ubuntu 18.04 WSL 2

PHP 8.0.3 **(cli)**

I installed Protoc from these [docs](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/)

```
muratcolyaran@MSI:~$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.0.0
```

I'm not sure is there any missing dependency in my OS. Or I'm missing any step here. But I'm really want to learn gRPC. So, If you have any advice, I'm looking forward to listening them

Comment: Why not install this through PECL? If something is not working according to the documentation, you should better open a support ticket in their issue tracker

Comment: pecl/grpc already installed but I need to generate libraries with protoc so I had to install gRPC C core and php plugin. Do you know any better idea to install them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that follow the link below. There is also a nice sample for you. After a long time which I stacked grpc installation for php, find this article and currently, I can create grpc applications easily

https://spiral.dev/docs/grpc-client

Exactly you need this section which I mentioned at picture:

[image]

After successfully installation just use the command below to generate your PHP code:

```
protoc -I. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc={GRPC_PATH} --php_out=. --grpc_out=. weather.proto
```

In my case `GRPC_PATH=/Users/anarrzayev/Documents/grpc-repo/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin`